# Rendering an an array of array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create an array of array in **reactjs** and render it. Currently,
I have an array and and I push one component to it and it gets rendered on the screen. However what i want is that after making my second selection, both first and second component should be seen on screen .

```
renderQuestions=()=>{
    let questions=[];
    console.log('rating',this.state.ratingType);


    if(this.state.ratingType=== '1'){
        questions.push(<NumberRating/>);
    }
    else if (this.state.ratingType === '2' ){
        questions.push( <StarRating/>);
    }
    else if (this.state.ratingType === '3'){
        questions.push( <PollRating/>);
    }

    console.log('Questions',questions);
    console.log('Length',questions.length);
    return questions;

}
```

and inside render I have

```
render(){
   return(
     <RaisedTextButton
                titleColor="white"
                title={'Add Question'}
                onPress={() => this.openDialog()}
            />
            <FormDialog
                title={'Select the kind of rating'}
                visible={this.state.visible}
                onRequestClose={()=>this.submitDialog()}
                onSubmit={()=>this.hideDialog()}

            >
                <Select
                    label='Label '
                    options={[
                        {_id: '1', name: 'NumberRating'},
                        {_id: '2', name: 'StarRating'},
                        {_id:'3', name: 'PollRating'}
                    ]}
                    labelKey="name"

                    onChange={(value) =>this.questionType(value)}
                    valueKey="_id"
                    isValueObject={!false}
                />
            </FormDialog>
               {this.renderQuestions()}
            </View>
  );}
```

Please note that I have a button in my render and on pressing this ,the state.ratingType changes .

Answer (score 1):

```
return (
   <React.Fragment>
      {this.renderQuestions().map(question => question)}
   </React.Fragment>
)
```

Here, this.renderQuestions() returns array. This needs to be wrapped with single node (Either div or if you dont have to use div, you can use React.Fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `return` code with this code. Actually when you call the method id return of `render()` it should return `jsx` or some text. But array is `js` variable and it will not we itself splitted in to parts to be `render()`. You need to but each of the component of the array in a container and then return it

```
return (
            <div className="container">
            {questions.map(question => (question))}
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: Or just `{...questions}`

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `array` in the **State** of the component, which holds the ratingType selection on click of the button and in the `render()` based on the array render the components.

```
Constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={
    questions:[]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A thought; your `if-else-if` branches can only ever allow you to render one of your ratingTypes. Is this intended? This has nothing to do with rendering lists; just JavaScript.

Two options for rendering lists:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {

  renderQuestions() {
    return [
      'a', 'b', 'c'
    ]
  }

  renderQuestionElements() {
    return [
      (<div>1</div>),
      (<div>2</div>),
      (<div>3</div>)
    ]
  }

  render() {
    const questions = this.renderQuestions()
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {questions.map((value, index) => (<div key={index}>{ value }</div>))}
        {this.renderQuestionElements()}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```